# Что делать если Windows 10 не загружается после обновления драйверов видеокарты?

Tags: windows, windows-10, драйвер, nvidia, видеокарта

Вчера сидел играл в Fallout 4 и друг системник неожиданно выключился и стал перезагружаться, но Windows так и не смог загрузить. Сегодня переустановил Windows 10, всё вроде нормально, в изображении нет никаких дефектов, но после того как я установил драйвера на видеокарту, то же самое. Перезапускается комп и Windows не может загрузиться.
Смог зайти через безопасный режим и моя видеокарта там отображается:
Nvidia Geforce GTX 560Ti
Делаю откат драйвера и компьютер снова включается как надо, до этого драйвера устанавливал те самые, которые устанавливал до поломки.
В чём может быть причина, подскажите пожайлуста что делать ?

Comment: Нагрузить furmark и посмотреть сдохнет или нет. Если да - проблема с видюхой и\или её охлаждением.

Comment: don Rumata как он проверит если компьютер не работает при установленных драйверах. Я бы на Win7 проверил если и там видеокарта глючит значит дело в ней. Если там все работает значит win 10 глючит или драйвера под нее.

Comment: Еще возможно блок питания перестал тянуть по мощности. Только чтобы это проверить нужен второй блок питания. Я еще бы питание видеокарты проверил вдруг там отошло. Особенно если она через переходник включена.

Comment: Дело не в блоке питания,я прозванивать и измерял все линии дополнительного питания,всё норм там